# Sort a table in ascending and descending order on clicking the header in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    let dir = "dsc";

    th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');



    for(let c=0; c < th.length; c++){
      th[c].addEventListener('click',item(c));
    }


    function item(c){
      return function(){
        if (dir == "asc") {
          dir = "dsc";
        }
        else {
          dir = "asc";
        }
        sortTable(c, dir);
      }
    }


  function sortTable(c, sort_dir) {
    let table_rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
    let table = document.getElementsByClassName("results_table");
    switching = true;
    table_rows = table[0].rows;
    while (switching) {
      // Start by saying: no switching is done:
      switching = false;

      for(i=0; i<(table_rows.length-1); i++){

        shouldSwitch = false;

        let present_row = table_rows[i];
        let next_row = table_rows[i+1];
             

        let present_percentage = present_row.cells[1].getElementsByClassName("row_values")[0].cells[1].innerText;
        let next_percentage = next_row.cells[1].getElementsByClassName("row_values")[0].cells[1].innerText;

        let present_percentage_length = present_percentage.length;
        present_percentage = present_percentage.substring(0, present_percentage.length-1);
        let next_percentage_length = next_percentage.length;
        next_percentage = next_percentage.substring(0, next_percentage.length-1);

        if(sort_dir == "asc") {
        if (parseInt(present_percentage, 10) > parseInt(next_percentage, 10)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;      
        }    
      }

        if(sort_dir == "dsc") {
        if (parseInt(present_percentage, 10) < parseInt(next_percentage, 10)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;      
        }    
      }

      }

      if (shouldSwitch) {
        table_rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(table_rows[i + 1], table_rows[i]);
        switching = true;
      }

      
    }
  }
  });
```

```html
<table class="results_table">
  
    <tr class="record">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table_class">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th>Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row_values">
            <td class="values">
              <td>68%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="record">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table_class">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th>Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row_values">
            <td class="values">
              <td>58%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="record">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table_class">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th>Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row_values">
            <td class="values">
              <td>53%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I have written a code that sorts the table rows according to column values in a single column. Right now the code sorts in the ascending order. How can I sort the table in descending order when the table is in ascending order and I click the same header? Here there are multiple tables inside the main table but I am just sorting by taking the rows of the main table. That is my present requirement. Right now I am able to sort in ascending order but cannot figure out how to add the descending order sorting on clicking the header. I must do this using vanilla Javascript. So I cannot use `jquery` or any other plugin.

Edit: I have edited the code snippet. This works according to the question but could you please tell me how to write the code in a more elegant, javascript way?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56231205/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with recreation steps and expected output

Comment: Added the `html` code. I have not added the complete table but this is the basic structure of the table.

Comment: Use datatable plugin simple.

Comment: The requirement is to do it using Vanilla Javascript. I cannot use jquery or any plugin.

Comment: Yeah, there is a reason for not inventing the wheel each time.

Comment: I know. I got the same reply when I asked another question related to the same topic but that is the requirement. I have to do it using vanilla Javascript and I have less knowledge about Javascript and HTML so not able to figure it out.

Comment: So start by making a [mcve] - the snippet gives error!

Comment: I have edited the code snippet.

Comment: You should start by moving your data from an HTML table to a JS array, and the other way around. Once you got that figured out, you can use filter, map and other array functions to order your table however you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few faults in our html which I corrected. After that the JavaScript can be simplified substantially by using the standard `Array.sort()` function. You need to convert the collection you get from `element.querySelectorAll()` into an Array by applying the `Array.prototype.slice.call()` method first though.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('th'),
               th=>{th.innerHTML='<a href="#" title="click here to sort!" >'+th.innerHTML+'</a>';
                    th.addEventListener('click',sortall)});
})

// access the sortable value in each row of the main table: look for the second row in each 
// sub-table, read the second cell and convert it to a number (by forcing the substraction:"-0")
function getVal(rw){
  return rw.querySelector('table').rows[1].cells[1].textContent.replace('%','')-0;
}

var dir=1;                                            // sort direction (values: 1 or -1)
var table = document.querySelector(".results_table"); // get table element

function sortall()  {
  let rows =  Array.from(table.rows);          // get rows collection as array
  rows.sort((a,b)=>dir*(getVal(a)-getVal(b)))  // sort the rows array
  rows.forEach(r=>table.appendChild(r))        // put rows back into main table
  dir=-dir                                     // toggle sort direction after each call
  return false
}
```

```css
th a {text-decoration:none}
```

```html
<table class="results_table">
    <tr class="record">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table_class">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th>Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row_values">
            <td class="values"></td>
            <td>68%</td>
            <td>88%</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="record">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table_class">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th>Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row_values">
            <td class="values"></td>
            <td>58%</td>
            <td>88%</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="record">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table_class">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th>Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row_values">
            <td class="values"></td>
            <td>13%</td>
            <td>88%</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="record">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table_class">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th>Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row_values">
            <td class="values"></td>
            <td>43%</td>
            <td>88%</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @Laxman: I have actually used your `Array.from()` method in two places now! Thanks for pointing it out - however, we need to keep in mind that this page will  work for "modern" browsers only ...